# tsconfig.json doesn't care about allowJs

Tags: javascript, angular, tsconfig

I am trying to use in my Angular 5 application a .js file which is avaible just in JavaScript language, so I can't find an alternative in TypeScript.

The problem is that I have added the `"allowJs": true` in my tsconfig.json, but the error is still active. My tsconfig.json is:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
'<path>/file.js' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: You can try to add checkJs: false to the config. And its better to post the error message.

Comment: Error added. checkJs: false doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Can you rename that file to `.ts`? Keep in mind that any valid `js` file is a valid `ts` file as well, so changing the extension shouldn't cause any trouble (other than the usual type warnings perhaps) and should get rid of the error.

Answer (score 10):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./built",
    "allowJs": true,
  }
}
```

You can only run `tsc` to compile your js file.

if u run `tsc file.js`, it will throw an error.

Because if you run `tsc`, it will find the nearest config file, but if you run `tsc file.js`, it will run depending on the default file(allowJs:false， ignore tsconfig.json).

Answer (score 1):

`allowJS`: Allow JavaScript files to be imported inside your project, instead of just `.ts` and `.tsx` files. (Please take a look into the [official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowJs), which should be available during 2022)

> The problem is that I have added the "allowJs": true in my tsconfig.json, but the error is still active.

That means your tsconfig.json is not referenced during compilation.

Answer (score 0):

"AllowJs" option allows you To accept js files as input for ts files.

You can migrate your js file to typescript, follow this link for more details:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html